# Performance Testing for Hybird App

Tags: jmeter

I am supposed to do a performance test for a Hybrid App.

First, from my adroid device i have modified the proxy settings by choosing Manual option and entered my system IP address as proxy server 192.168.1.10 and entered Port as 8080.

And then from Jmeter 3 i took Recording Controller Template from HTTPS Script Recorder I entered the port as 8080.

After Starting HTTPS Script Recorder when i opened my hybrid app it was not working. "Unfortunately we cannot find your account information". This means that Hybrid apps is not connecting internet through Proxy mode.

But i am able to get response from other apps installed in my android device.

I tried Neoload, Blazemeter as well https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/207420545-BlazeMeter-Proxy-Recorder-Mobile-and-web-.

But the same issue i faced every where.

Please provide me a solution to make the Hybird App work even after connecting internet through Proxy Mode.

Thanks

N Ali

Answer (score 0):

You need to find out the main error using i.e. [Logcat Command](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat.html) to narrow down the possible reasons as there could be too may of them.

The below hints are applicable for HTTPS traffic only, however I'm pretty sure that modern applications use HTTPS protocol.

1. You may need to use a 3rd-party application in order to set up HTTPS proxy, i.e. [ProxyDroid](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=org.proxydroid&hl=en_GB)
2. You will definitely need to install JMeter's self-signed certificate onto device so JMeter could decrypt and record secure traffic.

   - Locate `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` under "bin" folder of your JMeter installation and transfer it to your android device (i.e. send it to yourself via the email)
   - Click at the attached certificate
   - Follow android system certificate installation dialog to get it set up

Be aware that JMeter's certificate has limited life time (7 days) so you won't be able to record secure traffic if it is expired.

More information:

- [HTTPS recording and certificates](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder)
- [Load Testing Mobile Apps Made Easy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/load-testing-mobile-apps-made-easy)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Dimitri's answer reg JMeter, NeoLoad also has a similar CA certificate which needs to be added to the device.

You can locate this certificate from

```
C drive -> Users -> Username -> Appdata -> Roaming -> Neotys -> CA certificate
```

Copy this certificate to your device (or mail it to yourself) and install it either by directly selecting it or from the security settings.

Once the certificate is installed in the device, you should be able to record the HTTPs traffic from the application via proxy.

**P.S.** Ensure that you are able to view all hidden files coz by default Appdata is hidden.